# Why is my advice/pointcut not running at all?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, aspectj

Both 'aop:aspectj-autoproxy' and  'mvc:annotation-driven' are present in the XML config.
Both of these classes are defined as a bean inside of the same XML.

Using Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE and Google App Engine 1.8.1 in a local/dev environment.

My pointcut does not execute.

My advice. Declared inside a class annotated with @Aspect.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class RequestLimiter {
    private MemcacheService cache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();

@Pointcut("within(@pcs.annotations.LimitRequests com.zdware.pcs.controllers.PingCollectorController)")
public void methodRequestLimited(){}

 @Around("methodRequestLimited() && args(req,limitRequests)")
     public Object requestGateWay(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, HttpServletRequest req,LimitRequests limitRequests) throws Throwable {

     // do stuff

    }
}
```

The method I am using to test in the controller layer.

```
@Controller
public class PingCollectorController {
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
@LimitRequests(requestTimeLimit = 1, functionName = "Test")
public String test(){
    return "test"; // this will return me to a jsp that doesnt exist, but my advice is still not executing.
}
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is CGLIB in the classpath?  It will be needed to generate the proxy (since your controller does not implement an interface, spring cannot use a simpler JDK proxy).

Comment: I did not have it explicitly included as a dependency, but I just added it and still nothing :(

Comment: Yeah. I dont know. I'm really close to just implementing the advice as an actual method on the controller and just passing in the annotation values via reflection as parameters....

Probably the better performance too considering Google App engine prefers you hard code things rather then use xml/scanning.